# Use specific entry of an X macro

Tags: c, macros, x-macros

I am using X macros to generate functions setting GPIOs to `0` or `1` (I generate around 60 functions to set around 30 GPIOs). Here is an example (I have just written this example, so the syntax may be wrong):

```
/* X(pin_name, pin_nb) */
#define CPLD_GPIOs \
  X(Pin0, 0) \
  X(Pin1, 1) \
  X(Pin2, 2) \
  X(Pin3, 3)
```

I generate the functions to access to these GPIOs:

```
#define X(pin_name, pin_nb) \
  static void SetOn_GPIO##pin_name (void) { \
    SetOn_GPIOpins(pin_nb);\
    }
    CPLD_GPIOs
#undef X
```

The same process exists for `SetOff_GPIOXXX` functions.

Is there a way I can access the function generated above by the compiler as `SetOn_GPIOPin2` in an other part of the program without directly writing the function name? (In order to keep the code as global as possible)

At the end of preprocessing, we should only have `SetOn_GPIOPin2();` (and not every *X-macro* entries) generated from X-Macro.

Before pre-processing:

```
void foo ()
{
  /* some code */

  /* 
   * Macro to generate the desired function.
   * For e.g: SetOn_GPIOPin2();
   */

  /* some code */
}
```

After pre-processing:

```
void foo ()
{
  /* some code */

  /* Function resulting of the pre-processing */
  SetOn_GPIOPin2();

  /* some code */
}
```

Comment: Why can you not just write `SetOn_GPIOPin2();`?

Comment: @mkrieger1 : I could write `SetOn_GPIOPin2()`, but if someone or I decide to change the name of the pin in the `X-Macro` definition, I should change every call to this function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From comments on the question, your objective appears to be to protect against the case in which your X macro is modified to produce differently-named functions.  If that's so, then I think you're making unnecessary work for yourself: whether those names are changed is under your (and any other project developers') control, and a name change such as you are concerned about will not go unnoticed very long.  So *don't change them*.

But if you're determined to go this route then **no, there is no way to make the preprocessor extract the function names generated by your macros from their larger replacement text**.  Instead, you would need to *inject* them, via the same macro, into both the X macros and your other code.  Like this, perhaps:

```
/* X(pin_name, pin_nb) */
#define CPLD_GPIOs(gen) \
  X(Pin0, 0, gen) \
  X(Pin1, 1, gen) \
  X(Pin2, 2, gen) \
  X(Pin3, 3, gen)

// Generates the wanted function names:
#define GPIO_ON(pin_name, pin_nb) SetOn_GPIO##pin_name

#define X(pin_name, pin_nb, gen) \
  static void gen(pin_name, pin_nb) (void) { \
    SetOn_GPIOpins(pin_nb);\
    }
    CPLD_GPIOs
#undef X

// ...

void some_function(void) {
    GPIO_ON(pin_name, pin_nb)();
}
```

But note well that although this technique might have other applications, such as to generating multiple sets of functions with the same set of `X` macros, it just kicks the can down the road with respect to the specific objective you described.  You can rely on the name-generator macro to produce the same names for function declarations and function calls, but you still have the problem that the `X` macro can be modified to generate function declarations with different names.

Answer (score 0):

Using our trusty Boost.Preprocessor rocket launcher, this is preatty easy:

```c
#include <boost/preprocessor/tuple/rem.hpp>
#include <boost/preprocessor/control/if.hpp>
#include <boost/preprocessor/comparison/equal.hpp>

#define X_SELECT_PIN(pin_nb, selected_pin_nb, ...)  \
  BOOST_PP_TUPLE_REM_CTOR(BOOST_PP_IF(              \
    BOOST_PP_EQUAL(pin_nb, selected_pin_nb),        \
    (__VA_ARGS__),                                  \
    ()                                              \
  ))


// Usage

#define X(pin_name, pin_nb)\
  X_SELECT_PIN(pin_nb, 2, SetOn_GPIO##pin_name (void);)
  CPLD_GPIOs
#undef X
```

This uses `BOOST_PP_IF` to expand your pattern only for the selected pin. The added parentheses and `BOOST_PP_TUPLE_REM_CTOR` are there to protect the macro from expansions containing commas.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I don't know *Boost.Preprocessor*, I will have a look.

Comment: Boost is a C++ library, but the question is tagged C.

Comment: @JohnBollinger it is not. From [its documentation](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_74_0/libs/preprocessor/doc/index.html): "The library supports both C++ and C compilation. It does not depend on any other Boost libraries and therefore may be used as a standalone library."

Comment: Possibly Boost.Preprocessor in particular supports C as well as C++, which would certainly be relevant. But if so then it is very unusual among the Boost modules.  Overall, Boost is C++-specific.  It's mostly templates.

Comment: @JohnBollinger yes, I meant Boost.Preprocessor specifically, my bad.